# iText 2.1.7 by 1T3XT Toolbox error

Tags: java, batch-file, itext

When i'm launching my application through a bat file at the windows start up i'm getting this pop up error.    [image]

I have tried to add this concrete jar to the project, but it doesn't solve this problem. Despite this error the application runs smoothly. Another important nuance is that when i'm starting the application through IDE or by double clicking the jar file there is no track of this error. What is the case of this error and how to avoid it? Thank you for attention!

Comment: Please note that iText 2.1.7 has been declared dead a long time ago. That version is no longer supported and should no longer be used. Read the FAQ entry [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) for more info. If you are working for a customer, you should use a more recent version if you don't want your customer to be angry at you for selling ancient software that should no longer be used.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Oh wow, i didn't even notice that, just used it for text rendering. I'm going to explore closer into this matter, very useful information, thank you!

Comment: Add the jar file to the classpath when starting the app. Can you post the content of the bat file? You can do that by adding e.g. -cp path-to-jar